# how to center two images use Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

It works fine in big screen but on the mobile it's broken to two lines. One image on the left the other on the right.

HTML:

```
       <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 r"> 
                     <img src="img/qr.gif"> <br />
                    <p><small>HERE IS TITLE</small></p> 
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 l">
                    <img src="img/weixin.gif"> <br />
                    <p><small>HERE IS TITLE</small></p>                      
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 .l{text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;}
 .r{text-align: right; padding-top: 10px;}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Make them on the same line (and one will be on the left and the other on the right)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float`:

HTML:

```
<center>
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6 r"> 
                     <img src="img/qr.gif"> <br />
                    <p><small>HERE IS TITLE</small></p> 
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-6 l">
                    <img src="img/weixin.gif"> <br />
                    <p><small>HERE IS TITLE</small></p>                      
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
```

CSS:

```
 .l{display: block; padding-top: 10px; float: left; }
 .r{display: block; padding-top: 10px; float: right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2jag6/

Answer (score 0):

try using .pull-right on first image and .pull-left on second image.  no reason to create all new classes for classes already available in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

To keep both images in the same row in mobile view too, just add the bootstrap class `col-xs-6` class next to `col-md-6` class in your both divs, like:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
```